# Auto logout ASM after 10 minutes in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Our use case suggests logging out the customer support agent's session after 10 minutes, consequently routing to the `/login` page.

Say, the user stays idle in the homepage for 10 minutes, his session should logged out automatically and redirect to the `/login` page. Current scenario is, session is indeed logged out but the `/login` redirect is not happening.

This is different with the OOTB, wherein `logout` is explicitly triggered onClick of a button. And will execute if `isCustomerEmulationToken(token)` is true.

I'm trying my way using the `isCustomerEmulationSessionInProgress()` method in `AsmComponentService` but is unsuccessful since `isCustomerEmulationToken(token)` at this point is already false.

Is there a proper way to handle this in Spartacus?

Comment: Which version of Spartacus are you working with?

Comment: @LPatrick we're still using the old 1.5.x version